# PHP "unable to stat" error message

Tags: php

I often see this error message in my logs and it is pretty cryptic.  What does it mean when they say "unable to stat?"  Why does it happen?

Here is an example error message:
script /dir/dir/script_name.php' not found or unable to stat

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Can you edit your question with a few example error log messages?  There are a few reasons that you could see that message, so we'd want to know what you're seeing so we can explain it best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of time unable to stat means the specified file does not exist

Comment: File does not exist is indeed the most common cause.  And the second most common cause is probably permission denied.

Comment: Can I disable writing this error to my logs somehow?

Comment: Disabling a particular log message may be more of a webserver question.  I'd ask a new one for that